# text-overflow property is not working with Input element in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Text overflow with value **ellipsis** does not work in **IE 11** and **Edge** browsers on **windows 10**.I am using Angular material library's md-autocomplete element which uses input element.I have done the CSS change on it which works well in chrome and Mozilla.I created a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohanmanis/cvLhyhf4/1/) for it.

> css changes are:

```
md-autocomplete-wrap {

    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    overflow:hidden;

    }
    input {
        padding-right: 30px !important;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        margin: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        border: none;

    }
```

Comment: Fiddle link is already in the question.Please go through once.

Comment: Works fine here in IE edge. Maybe check if you messed with Document mode in your inpector? Also try clearing your cache..

Comment: Can you tell me about the OS and IE version?I am using windows 10 and IE11 and it's not working.It will be a great help if you can share the details.

Comment: Windows 10 latest update, IE edge 41.16299.15.0

Comment: The same configuration I am using.Maybe You are seeing dots in the dropdown rather than in the text box once you select that.because in the dropdown it is coming nicely(that is a <li> element which supports ellipsis in IE).